# Could COVID19 be considered as an ICAO abnormal or emergency situation?

Tags: emergency

Could COVID19 be considered as an abnormal or emergency situation as defined by ICAO:

> **Abnormal Situation:**
>
> A condition concerning the safety of an aircraft or other vehicle, or of some person on board or within  sight, but which does not require immediate assistance.
>
> **Emergency Situation:**
>
> A condition of being threatened by serious and/or imminent danger and of requiring immediate assistance.

Comment: Added both ICAO definitions of "Abnormal" and "Emergency" situations .

Comment: Thoses definitions applies only to one aircraft. Do you mean "could a covid19 case discovered among a passenger while still in flight be considered as an abnormal or emergency situation?" In that case, you should update your question to more clearer.

Comment: Recently happened multiple times the aircraft ferrying passengers to the home country while some of these passengers are knowingly sick with COVID-19, and other passengers probably might be. But I am not sure if you are asking about this or about the whole industry.

Answer (score 5):

No. An abnormal/emergency situation is a situation that applies to a single aircraft at a specific time. COVID-19 does not (generally) pose a specific risk to a specific aircraft. Obviously the entire aviation industry is in very bad shape at the moment, but that is not what we mean when we talk about an "emergency" in aviation.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I meant , "Emergency" is used in an ambiguous way .

Comment: @Ali no, there is nothing ambiguous about the way the word is used. Context matters